# CakePHP Auth Login without salt

Tags: php, cakephp, authentication, sha1

I am importing an old database to use with the cakephp platform and the previous user table did not have the passwords salted of any sort, it was only plain SHA1 used on them.

I am able to register accounts on CakePHP and they are stored plain SHA1 (thats how I want it done) but I am unable to successfully login to the accounts.

Any help?

Comment: Also if this helps, I am using the latest CakePHP build.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just set the hash to null Configure::write('Security.hash', null); should do it.